# IPP QBO v3 Reports API -- Filtering AgedReceivables Report by Class, Item, and Possibly Others

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

According to [the Documentation for QBO's v3 Reports API for AgedReceivables](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0400_references/reports/agedreceivables), I should be able to filter by class and item, but it doesn't seem to be working. (I successfully filtered by customer, so I don't think it's a syntax issue or something else more global like that.)

Here's the successful filter url I'm using:

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/[redacted]/reports/AgedReceivables?customer=77%2C106&report_date=2015-04-30
```

Here are the unsuccessful item and class queries I'm using (which simply return a report that's totally unfiltered):

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/[redacted]/reports/AgedReceivables?item=25%2C36%2C6%2C44%2C34&report_date=2015-04-30
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/[redacted]/reports/AgedReceivables?report_date=2015-04-30&class=3000000000000740741%2C3000000000000740740
```

I see nothing about this in the known issues, and would like clarification on what I'm seeing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are passing the Ids for item and class filters.
I too tried this and got all results. 
I have raised a bug for this-QBO-62935

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am passing the Ids...this is important functionality; any guidance on timing for a fix?

Comment: The team believes that these params might not be supported by the reports. They will work on identifying if these can be supported in a future release (normal time is around 2-3months) and will update the docs.

Comment: It just means incorrect info is present in docs and needs to be corrected